# Update variable when scrapy crawler is done

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to keep track of how many crawlers are done when im running multiple crawlers within a loop. What I've tried is to use signals but it seems like my crawlers cannot find other modules outside its scope. What I would like to do is to register that the crawling is done inside another script e.g. by passing/updating a variable.

Example code (shortened version - explaining problem):

**Controller.py**

```
isWikipediaDone = False
for file in Spiders:
    process.crawl(file)

print(isWikipediaDone)
```

**wikipediaSpider.py**

```
class WikipediaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 .... initialize ....

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(wikipediaSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print("Now we are done updating variable in Controller.py!")
        Controller.isWikipediaDone = True
```

Comment: Can you show where `Spiders`, `process`, and `Controller` are declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a controller class and later import it in your spider:

```
# controller.py
class Controller:
    def mark_as_done(self, spider):
        print("{} is done!".format(spider.name))
controller = Controller()
```

And connect controller method to your signal inside of your spider:

```
# myspider.py
from mypackage.controller import controller
...
crawler.signals.connect(controller.mark_as_done, signals.spider_closed)
```

Comment: Now I understand the signals better, thanks! Is there a way to remove the instance of the class in controller.py and just import the class inside the spider?

Comment: Solved the problem by making mark_as_done static, since im not editing anything